# Change Icon For Tkinter Messagebox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to change the icon of a tkinter  message box?
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

root = Tk()
messagebox.showinfo(title='Example',message='This is an example')
root.mainloop()
```

Is there an option to change the icon from the default tkinter feather to a custom ico?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is such an option. Assuming your root Tkinter instance is called `root`, your import statement is `from tkinter import *`, and your image file is named `'ico.gif'`:

```
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file='ico.gif'))
```

Call this method after creating the `root` object and before popping the `messagebox`. The icon will apply to the root object as well as to the `messagebox`.

Comment: First of all, which icon are you talking about? If it is that kind of rocket within the `messagebox`, then nothing changed. If you are talking about the root icon, then I don't know, because on this OS X, no icon is shown.

Comment: The "feather" is the image that appears in the title bar for Python 3 `tkinter` apps as seen [here](http://cnx.org/resources/f423ff5afe099b03fc3f24e63e0bc81607a3b60a/1359-1610-01.jpg). The above code works on Windows, but I don't have an OSX machine to test it on.

Comment: @nbro - It doesn't look like that sort of window icon appears in OSX applications at all, so I'm not surprised that it doesn't work for you. However, it should work for the OP. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: It is possible to do so on macOS by changing the `iconphoto(True, tk.PhotoImage(file='img.png'))` of the root window.

Answer (score 17):

Following are two possible solutions for your question:

**1. Changing the title bar icon**

Yes, we can set a custom icon for the title bar in tkinter.

[image: Set custom icon for title bar]

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

# change title bar icon
window.iconbitmap('book_2.ico')

window.mainloop()
```

**NOTE:** Use *.ico* files with the `iconbitmap()` function

If you set a custom icon for the root window, then this same icon will be set as the title bar icon for all other child window(s) including the message boxes from *messagebox* module.

[image: Root window and message box have the same custom icon]

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb

window = tk.Tk()

# change title bar icon
window.iconbitmap('book_2.ico')

# same icon is also set for the message box
tkmb.showinfo(title='Info', message='Info message box')

window.mainloop()
```

**2. Changing the icon inside message box**

**No** you *can not set* a custom icon for displaying inside of a message box.

[image: Message box icon]

But you have four preset icon options to choose from, the options are:

- **error**
- **info**
- **question**
- **warning**

[image: 4 message box icon options]

You can use them by specifying one of the above 4 values to the *icon* option.

```
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb

tkmb.showinfo(title='Message Box', message='Error message', icon='error')
tkmb.showinfo(title='Message Box', message='Info message', icon='info')
tkmb.showinfo(title='Message Box', message='Question message', icon='question')
tkmb.showinfo(title='Message Box', message='Warning message', icon='warning')
```

**NOTE:** The default icon for a

- `showinfo()` messagebox is *info*
- `showerror()` messagebox is *error*
- `showwarning()` messagebox is *warning*

Comment: Even if I use "iconbitmap()", the title icon is not changing. Could there be any other possible reason if someone knows? I will also post my image how it is along with code in the following answer

Comment: so theres no way to just remove it?

Comment: any way to get rid of the icon inside the `askyesno` box? it defaults to `info` when i put `None` :/

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without creating a root window before?

Comment: It's also possible to use the `iconphoto` method to use a `PhotoImage` object instead of a path to a bitmap icon file, whose format depends on the platform (i.e., ICO for Windows, XBM for Unix-like systems)