# How do I change the icon on a Tkinter error box? (Tried changing the "icon" parameter but did not work)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i am trying to change the icon for an messagebox error in Tkinter. I have set the parameter "icon" equal to "error" (which should the default), but I am still getting the Python logo as the icon.

Here is an example of my messagebox code:

```
messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Select a file!', icon='error')
```

The error message that is produced is the following:
[image]

Does anyone know the reason why the icon field isn't changing? I've tried in several different areas of my code but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Maybe try not filling the icon field? or use the showinfo box with same parameters, but it seems odd.

Comment: Tried both of those and neither worked :/ Seems like a bug or something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815007/change-icon-for-tkinter-messagebox - does this answer your question? I do not have the ability to mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using macOS. On macOS, the error icon and info icon defaults to the invisible window icon. To change this icon, use this code for the main window:

Assuming your root Tkinter instance is called root, your import statement is `from tkinter import *`, and your image file is named 'ico.gif':

```
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file='ico.gif'))
```