# Where are these files located?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

So, in this question:
[Change Icon For Tkinter Messagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815007/change-icon-for-tkinter-messagebox)

Somebody had mentioned that the default icons that come in the messagebox of tkinter: "Cannot be changed".
So does somebody know where this image is located, so that I can change it to my own image

Comment: For windows and OSX they are probably buried in the OS somewhere -- tkinter uses system dialogs whenever it can.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to make your own messagebox. Much easier than trying to change that icon. Here, I'll get you started:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, title='', message='', master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.title(title)

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=message, font=('bold', 14))
        lbl.pack()

        btn = ttk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.destroy)
        btn.pack()

        # The following commands keep the popup on top. Must be at the end of __init__
        self.transient(self.master) # set to be on top of the main window
        self.grab_set() # hijack all commands from the master (clicks on the main window are ignored)
        self.master.wait_window(self) # pause anything on the main window until this one closes

### TEST / DEMO CODE:

def show_custom_message():
    Popup("Title", "This is the popup message")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    lbl = tk.Label(text="this is the main window")
    lbl.pack()

    btn = tk.Button(text='click me', command=show_custom_message)
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All that's left is to stylize the popup any way you want.